# JavaScript pack integers and calculate arbitrary precision float:

Tags: javascript, binary-data, integer, arbitrary-precision

I need to do the following in JavaScript and so far been unable to find solutions to do it seamlessly:

- Grab two integers in a specific order and pack them like Python's struct module.
- This packed value, (bonus for supporting different endianness than host) will be turned into a 64 bit float (double). They must be arbitrary thus I might get an exponent representation of the integer (say, they could be 0xdeadbeef and 500):

  In exp form:
  1.0883076389305e-311
  1.0883076389305000 * 10 ^ - 311
- I need to convert it to the arbitrary precision, non-exponent form, so:

  0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000108830763893050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
- That number converted to a string :)

I haven't found a way to do this in Javascript and I have to output some numbers like that which must support arbitrary precision, or at least, of a scale up to the 1024 exponent (or, say 400) of doubles.

Thanks!!

Note: I do need the "packing/unpacking' to be a faithful representation of those two numbers converted to a double/64bit float. But I don't care about, say, exporting to a string or raw buffer. As long as I get an arbitrary precision double representation for the double it's all fine.

Comment: Haha, I would call a web service that does that on the server. Mind if I ask why you need to do that in javascript?

Comment: Because it's technically a challenge and Javascript these days thanks to JIT is much faster than doing the whole server side processing thing. No excuses to put more burden on the server.

Comment: @soze - on the server, packing two ints and unpacking them into a double would be trivial.

Comment: and so is on javascript, i thought it would be more complex. what isnt trivial is all the computational and telecommunications overload for such a simple procedure. it all adds up to far mroe than it's worth (doing in the client).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1: Khronos has a [specification in progress](http://www.khronos.org/registry/typedarray/specs/latest/#8) for a *`DataView`* interface as part of the WebGL *`TypedArray`* requirements, which combined with *`Int32Array`* and *`Float64Array`* would let you write your two ints into a buffer, and read them back out as a double.

Unfortunately browser support for this isn't common yet - to test your browser visit http://html5test.com/ and look at the section entitled "Native binary data".

Without the *`TypedArray`* support above I don't think there's any way to do this using bit-twiddling since Javascript's bit operators treat numbers as 32-bit unsigned values, so you'd have no access to the higher-order bits.

2: `double` variables don't have any specific form, IEE754 is just an internal representation.

3: *that's* the point at which you can attempt to show the actual precision.  Unfortunately the built-in method, e.g. `Number.toFixed()`, doesn't support showinng more than 20 decimal places.  You will need to parse the exponential form and manually construct a string with the appropriate number of leading zeros.

NB - the exponent range of a double is 2^1024, not 10^1024, hence the real limit is actually ~1.0E±308 - your example figure is smaller than that range.

**EDIT** actually, there might be a way, but I can't guarantee the precision of this:

1. take your two integers, call them `hi` and `lo`.
2. extract the exponent - `exp = (hi >> 20) & 0x7ff`
3. extract the sign - `sign = (hi >> 31)`
4. extract the mantissa - `((hi & 0xfffff) * Math.pow(2, 32) + lo) / Math.pow(2, 52)`
5. `result = (1 + m) * (Math.pow(2.0, exp - 1023))`
6. `if (sign) result *= -1`

**EDIT 2** - it works!  See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/assXS/

```
var hex2double = function(input) {

    var hi = parseInt(input.substring(0, 8), 16);
    var lo = parseInt(input.substring(8   ), 16);

    var p32 = 0x100000000;
    var p52 = 0x10000000000000;

    var exp = (hi >> 20) & 0x7ff;
    var sign = (hi >> 31);
    var m = 1 + ((hi & 0xfffff) * p32 + lo) / p52;
    m = exp ? (m + 1) : (m * 2.0);

    return (sign ? -1 : 1) * m * Math.pow(2, exp - 1023);
};
```

Enter a floating point number at http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html, take the resulting hex string from the bottom row of output, and pass it to the function above.  You should see an alert containing the original value.

**EDIT 3** code fixed to account for the special case when the exponent bits are all zero.

Comment: I was asking for a JS-only solution, I can't depend on anything else ;(

Comment: Oh, regarding the string representation, why do you suggest simply prefixing it with zeroes? I mean, sure the product of * 10 ^300 will be a tiny number, prefixed with as many zeroes... But if you can show an example of that working for any arbitrary number I would appreciate it.

Comment: the built-in JS types don't support arbitrary numbers, they only support IEE754 double format.

Comment: i only need a 64 bit double... and i only need the arbitrary precision lib to convert it to non exponential representation to send it to a web service, which requires it that way. im still unsuccessful in my search for a pack/unpack mechanism to handle the two integers.

Comment: hm, thanks for all the effort but, i just tested with 1.0883076389305e-311 (512 + 0xdeadbeef, 00000200DEADBEEF) and your function returns 1.113081083073066e-308, which it's not right.

Comment: Again, what I need is a function that given a number/64 bit double 1.0883076389305e-311 will return the string '(...)00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000108830763893050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' (see orig question) which corresponds to the decimal non-exponent representation of it. and it lets you use 0-0xffffffff mostly.

Comment: how about packing two integers X and Y into an array of bytes Z, and Z turned into a proper number/double that i can feed into a arbotrary precision lib for JS?

Comment: @soze special case for _very_ small numbers fixed. The function was fine for all numbers except those with e < 10e-308

Comment: ill check, packing issue solved, with Struct ala jspack, first packing the two integers then unpacking them into float, and from there ive checked with BigInteger but seems i havent found the right way to do the exponent expansion, kind of sucks.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a big number library for JavaScript such as http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber.