# float to byte (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

In function is transmited double.

```
function writebyte(id, data)
{
    data = Math.floor(data);
    buf[id] = String.fromCharCode(data & (255));
}
```

It works ok for 0-127 values. But with negative or > 127 works wrong.

```
128 = 0xC2 0x80 (should be 0x80 1 byte)
-1  = 0xC3 0xBF (should be 0xFF 1 byte)
```

So I think problem is function `String.fromCharCode` with parameter 128++ or negative.

Is there any way writing bytes to array directly without String.fromCharCode?

Comment: It looks like you are wanting to be able to represent numbers greater than +127 with 8 bits yet also represent negative numbers with twos complement binary with the MSB acting as -128. You can't do both...

Comment: I dont understand. Why cant I do both? -1 == 255 == 0xFF -2 == 254 == 0xFE. buf is sent by websocket protocol i just want that if i transmit -1 or 255 to this function first byte would be 0xFF (for example)

Comment: 128 == 0x80. There no -128 (max signed is -127)

Comment: Well conventionally the most-significant bit is made negative (ie -128) giving a range of -128 to 127 for a signed bit. I'm not sure if you are using a different system?

Comment: You are right. So signed range -128 to 127. Unsigned 0 to 255. But this doesnt solve my question. I want transmit in function -1 and in data[id] should be 0xFF or I transmit 255 and in data[id] should 0xFF and so on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5620/discussion-between-demion-and-el-ronnoco)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757956/javascript-pack-integers-and-calculate-arbitrary-precision-float/6758076#6758076) you will find JavaScript code that will convert from (hex) bytes into a double.  [JS doesn't have "floats"]

Reversing the process is left as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: -1; Byte operations in JS convert the double to an intermediate integer representation. They do not operate on the actual floating point representation.

Comment: @missingno you're missing the point - by manipulation of the original floating point number it is possible to calculate the sign, mantissa, and exponent, and from there work out the correct IEE754 representation thereof.  The code I previously posted does that in reverse.

Comment: Doesnt Math.floor convert float to integer?

Comment: @Demion no, not really, it just removes the fractional component.  In any event, can you clarify your question - it now appears that you're really only talking about _small integer_ values, and not _doubles_ at all!

Comment: Yes i work only with -128 .. 127 or with 0..255. But another (not mine) code transmits double to this function.

Comment: Is there any way writing bytes to array directly without String.fromCharCode?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you please make reverse function double2hex?